# Do Service Fabric singleton services have downtime when scaling?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We use a Service Fabric cluster to deploy stateless microservices. One of the microservices is designed as a singleton. This means it is designed to be deployed on a single node only.

But does this mean when we scale up or scale down the VM scale set (horizontal scaling) the service will be down? Or does the Service Fabric cluster take care of it?

Comment: One of the replica's will take over, so you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what will happen in case of vertical scaling? I mean what if I want to increase the VM memory or CPU? Will that be a downtime?

Comment: It will go ok as well, withouth downtime *if* you follow the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scaling#scaling-up-and-down-or-vertical-scaling)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main concepts do keep in mind about services in service fabric, mainly but not limited to Stateful Services. **Partitions** and **Replicas**.

**Partitions** define the approach used to split the data into groups of data, they are  [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning#get-started-with-partitioning) as:

- **Ranged** partitioning (otherwise known as UniformInt64Partition). Used to split the data by a range of integer values.
- **Named** partitioning. Applications using this model usually have data that can be bucketed, within a bounded set. Some common examples of data fields used as named partition keys would be regions, postal codes, customer groups, or other business boundaries.
- **Singleton** partitioning. Singleton partitions are typically used when the service does not require any additional routing. For example, stateless services use this partitioning scheme by default.

When you use **Singleton** for Stateful services, it assumes the data is managed as a single group, no actual data partition is used.

**Replicas** defined the number of copies a partition will have around the cluster, in order to prevent data-loss on a primary replica failure.

In summary,

If you use a Singleton partition, shouldn't be a problem if the number of replicas is at least 3.

That means, once one NODE gets updated, the replica hosted on that node will be moved to another node, if this replica being moved is a primary replica, it will be demoted to secondary, a secondary will be promoted to primary, and then the demoted replica will shutdown and replicated onto another node.

The third replica is needed in case a replica fails during an upgrade, then the third get promoted to primary.